# Out of Memory; BERT

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model

I am new in this area and trying to learn through the below Github link.
However, I have encountered a runtime error. Despite tweaking the batch size and gradient accumulation to smaller values, and clearing the cache, the runtime error persists.

Can anyone share any insight on this? Thanks very much.

https://github.com/nlptown/nlp-notebooks/blob/master/Text%20classification%20with%20BERT%20in%20PyTorch.ipynb

> RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 1024.00 KiB (GPU 0; 4.00 GiB total capacity; 3.09 GiB already allocated; 528.00 KiB free; 32.48 MiB cached)

Comment: What is the exact place where you encounter the error? (Can you include the exact snippet into the question?) 4 GB GPU RAM is rather small. How much is occupied when you just load the model. Gradient accumulation should not matter. Try also reducing `MAX_SEQ_LENGTH`. BERT needs quadratic memory w.r.t. to sequence length.

Comment: There are three ways to evade this problem: a. reduce the batch size, b. reduce the MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, If a & B doesn't work, your GPU might not be sufficient enough, because of which try considering c. Executing on CPU (Which might be terribly slow)

Comment: Thank you all, I am able to run it after changing the MAX_SEQ_LENGTH

Comment: I encountered the error at the step of getting the outputs.                                                 outputs = model(input_ids, attention_mask=input_mask, token_type_ids=segment_ids, labels=label_ids)